# Comparing structure of files

Tags: command-line, bash, rsync

I got 2 structures of dirs:

```
dir1
├── 1
│   └── file1
├── 2
│   └── file1
├── 3
│   └── file1
├── 4
│   └── file1
├── 5
    └── file1
```

```
dir2
├── 1
├── 2
├── 5
```

I use `xargs mkdir -p < dirs.txt` to make file.txt with names of dirs. In this file i got only paths to dirs, without files in dirs. How take out paths of files only includes list of dirs in `dirs.txt`?

For example: I need take out from `dir1` structure of dirs from `dir2` with files from `dir1`. This should look like `dir3`:

```
dir3
├── 1
│   └── file1
├── 2
│   └── file1
├── 5
│   └── file1
```

On last step I will use:
`rsync -a /source/directory --files-from=/full/path/to/listfile /destination/directory`

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `find`. It can be instructed using the `-type` flag to only find directories, and with the `-path` flag, only find items matching a path. For example,

```
find . -path './dir1/*' -type d
```

will only list all directories and subdirectories under `dir1`. You can then redirect that to a `dirs.txt` file, and edit that file the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Difficulty with these tasks is usually when you need to match something in the middle of the path, in this case, it seems you can match the second level from the two directory lists. I also assume you do not have, e.g., newlines in any of the paths.

```
awk -F / -vOFS=/ -vf=2 'NR==FNR {a[$f]++; next} $f in a {$1=""; print $0}' \
      <(printf %s\\n dir2/*) dirs.txt | rsync -avx --files-from=- dir1/ dir3
```

Setting the delimiter `-F` to `/` basically makes *fields* out of the different path components, the path component after the *starting-point* will become the 2nd field. The first pattern action  `NR==FNR {}` reads the first file into the array, which is the directory list of `dir2`. When the first file reaches the end, `NR==FNR` becomes false and the second file will be processed by the next pattern action. Before printing the path, *starting-point* has to be removed to account for the source/ destination of rsync.